# getche() showing special character as another value

Tags: c, character, ascii

i am doing a coding exercise, where i read user inputs with `getche()` in c, since im portuguese, i need to let the user input portuguese special characters, such as "Á" etc...
And i cant seem to output those in the screen, it saves the character just fine, but for example when i press "Á" it shows in screen "µ"
The following code is the part where i read the user input with `getche()`:

```
int counter = 0;
    int inner_counter = 0;
    int amount = 0;
    int entrada = 0;
    int especiais[16] = {128, 144, 181, 192, 183, 199, 210, 212, 214, 224, 226, 227, 228, 233, 234, 235};

    printf("\nAqui apenas sera aceite letras Maisculas e espaço!\n");
    printf("Introduza quantos caracteres deseja inserir!\n");
    scanf("%d", &amount);

    int array_tipo1[amount];  //array dinamico, tamanho com base na preferencia do user, dynamic array

    for(counter=0;counter<amount;counter++){
        entrada = getche();  #where i read the input FIX: entrada = getwchar();

        if((entrada >= 65 && entrada <= 90) || (entrada == 32)){
            array_tipo1[counter] = entrada;
        }

        else if(entrada >= 128){
            for(inner_counter=0;inner_counter<16;inner_counter++){
                if (entrada == especiais[inner_counter]){
                    array_tipo1[counter] = entrada;
                }
            }
        }

        else{
            array_tipo1[counter] = '\0';
        }
    }

    for(counter=0;counter<amount;counter++){
        if(array_tipo1[counter] != '\0'){
            printf("\n%c\n", array_tipo1[counter]);
        }
    }
```

the numbers im using the ASCII table numbers referencing the characters that i will let the user input
appreciate it in advance guys!

Comment: The *code page* setting defines the character set that is used for non-ASCII characters on the Windows console. A text editor is possibly using UTF-8. If I enter `chcp` is replies `Active code page: 850`.

Comment: Please see [How to change ANSI Code Page (ACP) on Windows](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/4677).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The letters with accents you are trying to use are multiple bytes, the getche() only uses the first byte. To use those characters you will have to use getwche() instead.

Comment: thx for you help men! used `the getwchar()` worked like a charm!